# MSBuild publish website with embedded resources

Tags: msbuild

I'm using the command-line to call msbuild to generate a published version of a website using this command:

```
msbuild.exe /t:ResolveReferences;Compile;_CopyWebApplication /p:OutDir=dir/bin/ 
    /p:WebProjectOutputDir=dir/ /p:Debug=false /p:Configuration=Release 
    Website.csproj
```

This works fine other than the embedded resources not being present in the `Website.dll`. If I do the publish via Visual Studio it includes the embedded resources. Is there a flag I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears

```
/t:PrepareResources
```

calls all the targets youve added to your msbuild call, try that

heres the top few levels of what gets called

```
PrepareResources 
    PrepareResourceNames
        AssignTargetPaths
        SplitResourcesByCulture
        CreateManifestResourceNames
        CreateCustomManifestResourceNames
    ResGen
        ResolveAssemblyReferences
        SplitResourcesByCulture
        BeforeResGen
        CoreResGen
        AfterResGen
    CompileLicxFiles
```

Answer (score 4):

An extra target is required like so:

```
msbuild.exe /t:PrepareResources;ResolveReferences;Compile;_CopyWebApplication 
    /p:OutDir=dir/bin/ /p:WebProjectOutputDir=dir/ /p:Debug=false 
    /p:Configuration=Release Website.csproj
```

Comment: How did you solve the problem. Did you capture the VS build output? How?

Comment: I made VS output the build process "Detailed": Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity. Then I looked at every target that related to resources and added it in. I've found that more than the one argument seems to be required now by the way. I've updated the above answer.

Comment: are they all called from a single target under the .csproj? there might be an abstracted target you can call instead of all those individual ones

Comment: try microsoft.common.targets and microsoft.chsarp.targets